# Relationship between Taylor, Laurent and Fourier series

Tags: taylor-expansion, fourier-series, laurent-series

What are your thoughts about the answer of this PhD holder in mathematics about the relationship between Laurent, Taylor (or Maclaurin) and Fourier series?

Did a textbook author made a nice mindmap (flowchart) that highlights the relationships/differences between these three kind of series? I would greatly like to do a very pedagogical illustration highlighting the relationships/differences between all of them (with Tikz for example).

[Quora relationship Laurent, Fourier, Taylor series](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-relationship-between-the-Fourier-series-and-the-Taylor-series)

For example, if a function has a Taylor series and a Laurent series about a point then the two coincide. Which means the function is analytic at that point.

Thanks for your feedbacks

Comment: It is a bit misleading. The Taylor series at $a$ of an analytic function is the same as the Fourier series of $f(a+r e^{it})$ for  $r < R$ with perhaps $R$ very small. Same for the Laurent series but with $r\in (R_1,R_2)$.